# Error . operator < cannot be applied

Tags: java, generics, compiler-errors

In Line 11 there is an error .

```
operator < cannot be applied to java.lang.Object,java.lang.Object
```

I don't quite understand this but then again I'm new to generics in Java . bear with me please.

```
public void sortbykey()
 {
     LinkedList temp = new LinkedList();
     LinkedList third = new LinkedList();
     temp=head;

     if(temp!=null)
     {
       while(temp.next!=null)
       {
               if (temp.key < temp.next.key)
               {
                 third.item = temp.key;
                 temp.key = temp.next.key;
                 temp.next.key = third.item;
               }
               else
                   temp = temp.next;
       }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Do you understand that `Object`'s cannot be compared with `<` ?

Comment: What is `LinkedList` used in `LinkedList temp`? It seems that it is your own type since standard one doesn't have `key` field. Anyway it looks like this field is of type Object and comparing Objects with `<` doesn't make sense (how would `new Bike()` should be compared with `new Banana()`?).

Answer (score 5):

To compare non-numeric types, you would need to implement `Comparable` on that type and use `temp.key.compareTo(temp.next.key) < 0` instead.

If you were using a `LinkedList<? extends Number>`, it would not be applicable due to [type erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html). However, if you specify a concrete implementation that wraps a primitive to which the `<` operator is applicable (see [autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html)) such as `LinkedList<Integer>`, then it would be possible since `Integer` is specified as the bound, `Integer` wraps `int`, and the `<` operator is applicable to `int`.

In your case, since you are using a raw type, the bound is `java.lang.Object`, to which the `<` operator is not applicable. Just like those of us reading your question, we can't tell if the `LinkedList` is of a type to which the `<` can be applied.

Raw types should be generally avoided anyway as they effectively strip generics of their value.

Answer (score 2):

Simply, this operator can be applied on numeric types, such as `int`, `byte`, `double`, `float`, etc and their boxing classes (such as `Integer`, `Byte`, etc.).

It doesn't work combined with Generics, because the compiler doesn't know the exact types of the operands. When working with Generics, these types are set at Runtime, after the type erasure has occurred.

A possible solution for you is to make the class of the `key` property implement the `Comparable<T>` interface and then you will be able to compare it with:

```
temp.key.compareTo(temp.next.key) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell for sure because you haven't posted the data structure of your Node and LinkedList, but it looks like whatever you're storing in 'key' is not a java primitive so you can't use the '<' operator. make sure key is something like an int or float to use <. Otherwise you will need to use a class method on the type of 'key'. For example if 'key' is a String, you could use ("apple").compareTo("banana");